# Raspberry Pi 4 crashing(?) after OS is installed

Tags: pi-4, boot-issues, ubuntu

I am trying to boot up my raspberry pi 4, but the green light (next to power) keeps blinking and then shutting down!

I was able to install Ubuntu Desktop on the 32GB microSD, but as soon as I tried to sign in, it stops working (power stays on and keyboard is lit up, but no monitor).

While I was installing Ubuntu on it I was already experiencing some short (less than a second) blackouts of my green light as well.

EDIT: I am using the CanaKit with a fan.And when I do not add the microSD I get a solid green light (obviously still no screen)

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: Could mount the SD card on a different machine, and look at /var/log/boot.log  See if there are any errors. Or just try re-imaging the SD card, might have gotten corrupt or something.

Comment: `the green light (next to power) keeps blinking and then shutting down!` - an LED doesn't "shut down" - does the green LED blink in a particular pattern? `short (less than a second) blackouts of my green light as well.` since the green LED is usually the disk activity LED, then that's not really relevant

Comment: `as soon as I tried to sign in` - so, you get as far as a graphical log in screen?

Comment: `as soon as I tried to sign in` ... don't log in ... just let it sit for 20 minutes ... does it stay at the login screen?

Comment: I got to the login screen once, then it died.
Restarting it then just gave me a blank screen the entire time, along with no green light.